# Timestamp convert of US date format

Tags: php, date

I have date in this format `'m-d-Y'` (12-31-2017). I want to convert it into a `timestamp`. Normally, this works:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

But if I am not mistaken, that works with `'d/m/Y'` and not `'m/d/Y'`.

What's the solution here?

Comment: *I have date in this format 'm/d/Y' (12-31-2017)* - that string doesn't match that format. For reference, `strotime` works fine with m/d/Y dates, but it's always cleaner to use `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)** and then call `getTimestamp()` on the Object:

```
//first create DateTime Object
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '12-31-2017');
//get timestamp from DateTime
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .

```
<?php
$d=strtotime("12/31/2017");
echo "Created date is " . date("m-d-Y h:i:sa", $d);
?>
```

[Output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b53e4ea41570f8c4787d5992f2e2906102f75868)

for more Information about date time format then read [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: Have you actually looked at the output you posted? I don't think **12-31-1969** is the right answer.

Comment: @iainn i have update my answer

Comment: @AniketSahrawat  i have update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change date according your format :

```
$date = '12/31/2017';

$timestamp = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

$timestamp = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));

$timestamp = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($date));
```

if Timestamp

```
$timestamp = date('m-d-Y h:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Did you try running this? `strtotime('12-31-2017')` returns false.

Comment: it's output is wrong check this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/79eb44b6ee47dd820c8e1cc3c9867466f65badb8

Comment: I changed my code now check please

Answer (score 0):

An another solution is the following:

```
//CONVERT the time string from the desired format
$dateTime=DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$date);

echo "UNIX TIMESTAMP method 1".$date->format("U");
// false
echo "UNIX TIMESTAMP method 2".$date->getTimestamp();
```